# Why is Narada called brahmachari if he is married?

Tags: devi-bhagavata-purana, narada, brahmacharya

The following excerpt from [*THE SIXTH BOOK, Chapter XXVII*](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk06ch27.htm) of the S'rîmad Devî Bhâgawatam clarifies that Narada married Damayantî.

> Nârada said :-- On hearing the words of her daughter Damayantî, that
>   unblameable pure queen knowing her attachment deep towards me, spoke
>   to the King thus :-- “O King! Now celebrate in an auspicious day and
>   on an auspicious moment the auspicious marriage of Damayantî; the
>   daughter has said that she has already selected Nârada as her
>   bridegroom and it cannot be other-wise.” **Thus prompted by the queen,
>   the King S’anjaya performed the marriage ceremony of her daughter in
>   accordance with due rites and customs and in an exceedingly becoming
>   manner. O Risi! Thus I entered into the married life and remained
>   there though my heart constantly burned with the thought of my
>   monkey-face.** Whenever the princess used to come to me for my service,
>   I used to get tormented with the remembrance of my monkey-face; but
>   her face beamed with gladness whenever she saw me; never she became
>   sorry nor dejected, even for a moment, to see my face monkey-like.
>   Thus time passed on. One day the Muni Parvata suddenly came there,
>   after making his sojourn to many places of pilgrimages. I showed him a
>   great respect and gladly loved him and greeted him duly; he got
>   himself seated in an excellent Âsana and became very sorry to see me.
>   I am his uncle and have entered into a married life; my face has
>   become monkey-like. Therefore I am very much depressed in spirits and
>   worried with the sad thought and has become lean and thin. Seeing this he was overwhelmed with pity. He then said :-- “O Muni! The curse that I cast on you before out of my anger, I now withdraw. Hear. O Maharsi! Let your face be by my merits, again as good as it was before; I now feel pity for the daughter of the King.”

Is it true that Narada is brahmachari? If no, then why is he called so if he is already married?

Note: The question marked as duplicate says in general. In order to validate it for Narada, there is a need to show that he follows that. So, please provide statements regarding the brahmacharya of Narada. Because, otherise, we can consider all gods such as siva, Brahma etc., as brahmacharis.

Comment: Consider the question once again.

Comment: This question has been incorrectly marked as duplicate.

Comment: "Whenever the princess used to come to me for my service"- as u hv this and not in opposite way..as per Indra's boon to women even if wife approach husband on prohibited days, husband doesn't get any sin...so Narada still can be considered Brahmchari and he is dev rishi so most probably he must hv followed rules to remain Brahmchari...bdw even Hanuman is married so marriage is not a factor to consider at all... Krishna who had many wives and sons still called Brahmchari..i don't think it's closef incorrectly...if so we may hv many such Q on each spiritual person..

Comment: bdw why u should not consider Shiva Brahmchari...he is great yogi and Brahmcharya is one of the important part of yama-niyama very basic step of yoga...